# python3 use logging to log all elements in a container(list, or tuple)

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

In Python3, if we want to print all elements in a list, we can simply do

```
lst = ['a','b', 'c']
print(lst)
```

In this way, we can print out all elements in a list. 
Suppose now I use logging to log everything, instead of print it out to the screen, for a debug purpose, how to log all elements in a container ( i.e list, or tuple) ?

I can think of something like :

```
for it in lst:
     log.info("element is {i}".format(i = it))
```

but this is too ugly. Any suggestion?

I also refer [Howto](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html) , but did not get much input.

Comment: Is it the code that you consider too ugly, or the log message that's produced?

Comment: what about `log.info("element is {}".format(",".join(map(str,lst))))`

Comment: The ``print`` example outputs the entire list, the ``log`` example outputs each element. Which do you need?

Comment: What's wrong with `log.info(lst)`?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out. Yes, just like@Patrick Haugh said, we can just use `loog.info(lst)` to log all elements in the list, just works similarly to `print`.

Thank you all!